# Widgets not showing in my custom theme

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, themes, widgets

I am developing this WordPress custom theme: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap and I am trying to insert a **widget area** under the **Partner e Sostenitori** section, but can't work.

I have performed the following operations:

1) I have put the following code into the **functions.php** theme file:

```
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'My_Widgtet_Area',
        'id' => 'partner-slide',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init');
```

As you can see the name of the widgetized area is **My_Widgtet_Area**

2) Then I have insert the following code into my **index.php** file to show the widgets in the desired positions:

```
<section id="partnerSlide">
    <header class="header-sezione">
        <h2>Partner e Sostenitori</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            // 'My_Widgtet_Area' area, where the id is called:
            if (is_active_sidebar( 'My_Widgtet_Area' ) ) : ?>

            <div id="widget-sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'My_Widgtet_Area' ); ?>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- #widget-sidebar .widget-area -->

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

3) Then I entered in the WP administration panel and into the **Appearance ---> Widget** section I have the **My_Widget_Area** "box" where I can drag the widgets in my wordpress installation. So I put in it some widget (as the **Calendar** and the **Search** wigets) to try it

The problem is that, as you can see in the previous link, the **Partner e Sostenitori** text is written but there is no widget displayed in my page.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the widget name and not i.d which is why it isn't working.

Change this:

```
if (is_active_sidebar( 'My_Widgtet_Area' ) ) : ?>

        <div id="widget-sidebar">
            <ul>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'My_Widgtet_Area' ); ?>
            </ul>
```

To this:

```
if (is_active_sidebar( 'partner-slide' ) ) : ?>

        <div id="widget-sidebar">
            <ul>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'partner-slide' ); ?>
            </ul>
```

The i.d in the template tag  immediately above should match the i.d you use to register the widget in your functions file which in this case is `partner-slide`

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'My Widget Area',
    'id' => 'partner-slide',
```

That's one obvious problem and there may be others however you should follow the Codex as it provides working examples with related links http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Comment: it seems to work but now I have the following problem: if (for example) I reneam 'partner-slide' as 'partner-slide-2' (in all occurrences: in the index.php and in functions.php) don't work...why?

Comment: It will as long as they match. Clear your browser cache and populate the widgets again in the Widgets admin area.

Comment: I think that I have understand by myself what was the problem: simply I have to reload the backend section in wich I insert the widget voices after that I change the id value